# Help with drawing Process Flow Diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get started with drawing this flow chart in TikZ?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30914/how-to-get-started-with-drawing-this-flow-chart-in-tikz)

I was wondering if I can get any hit/help drawing a process flow diagram such as the one in the attachment. Thank you for all the help/hint/or link to the similar examples.[image: Sample Process flow diagram]

Comment: On this site, a question should typically revolve around an abstract issue (e.g. "How do I get a double horizontal line in a table?") rather than a concrete application (e.g. "How do I make this table?"). Questions that look like "Please do this complicated thing for me" tend to get closed because they are "too localized". Please try to make your question clear and simple by giving a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228): you'll stand a greater chance of getting help.

Comment: I found this example: http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/simple-flow-chart/ I think this could be very helpfull for you.

Comment: I think you would do a better one than this which is just ugly (font-, shape-, and process-wise).

Comment: There are also lots of related questions on this site, e.g., [How to get started with drawing this flow chart in TikZ?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30914/how-to-get-started-with-drawing-this-flow-chart-in-tikz)

Comment: @BenediktBauer: I didn't expect you to draw a diagram for me! What I meant was any HINT or similar example that the other user may have come across. I am glad that other users didn't have the same understanding as you and referred to similar examples.

Comment: @Dave: Yes, it is very similar. Thank you :)

Comment: @percusse: Well, this looks much better on pdf, I don't know why it looks so bad here...